# Storing values from components into a global service

Tags: angular, angular-services, angular2-observables, behaviorsubject

I am trying to create a global service which will store the data from components, and using this global service I want to create a breadcrumb based on the specific values present in the service.
I have the following implementation. I am unable to get the values of ids from individual components into global service. I am not sure if the way of setting these ids into a service is right, or is there any other way.

Global Data Model

```js
export interface GlobalData {
    id1: number;
    id2: number;
    id3: number;
    id4: number;
}
```

Global Service

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { GlobalData } from 'src/models/GlobalData';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class GlobalDataService {
  public globalData$ = new BehaviorSubject<any>('');
  globalData = this.globalData$.asObservable();
  constructor() { }
  changeGlobalData(globalData: GlobalData) {
    this.globalData$.next(globalData)
  }
}
```

Component1

```js
export class Component1 implements OnInit {

  constructor(private globalDataService : GlobalDataService ) {
  } 
  globalData: GlobalData[] = [];
  this.globalDataService.globalData$.subscribe( x=> this.globalData = params?.data?.id1);
```

Component2

```js
export class Component2 implements OnInit {

  constructor(private globalDataService : GlobalDataService ) {
  } 
  globalData: GlobalData[] = [];
  this.globalDataService.globalData$.subscribe( x=> this.globalData = params?.data?.id2);
```

Similarly, I am doing for Component3 and Component4.
My goal is to use these values of ids that I get from component to store at global service so that I can use that in breadcrumb as follows:
BreadcrumbComponent

```js
export class BreadcrumbComponent {

  breadcrumbs$: Observable<Breadcrumb[]>;

  constructor(private readonly breadcrumbService: BreadcrumbService) {
    this.breadcrumbs$ = breadcrumbService.breadcrumbs$;
  }

}
```

breadcrumb.component.html

```html
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let breadcrumb of (breadcrumbs$ | async)">
    <a [href]="breadcrumb.url">{{ breadcrumb.label }}</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Can you share the src of `BreadcrumbService` ?

Comment: It doesn't look like you are setting the values in the service anywhere. When do you expect those ids to update?

Comment: @DavidKidwell data is set using this method `changeGlobalData`

Comment: I see that defined, but I don’t see it being called.

Comment: I think your issue is in your corresponding components you are consuming the behavior subject and not the observable, try subscribing to the observables in your components and not the behavior subjects

Comment: @GarrettWitzenburg I am not sure how that should be done

Comment: @DavidJackson He means you subscribed to `this.globalDataService.globalData$` the `BehaviorSubject` instead of `this.globalDataService.globalData` the `Observable`. Doesn't make a difference in this context though.

Answer (score 0):

This function:

```js
  changeGlobalData(globalData: GlobalData) {
    this.globalData$.next(globalData)
  }
```

Implies that you're sending a single object of type `GlobalData` through the BehaviourSubject. So I really have no idea what these two lines of code are:

```js
globalData: GlobalData[] = [];
this.globalDataService.globalData$.subscribe( x=> this.globalData = params?.data?.id1);
```

Should be:

```js
globalData?: GlobalData;
this.globalDataService.globalData$.subscribe( x => this.globalData = x);
```

Keep in mind doing it like this may not fire change detection when you re-assign `this.globalData`. That's because subscription callbacks happen outside of the `NgZone`. You may need to force change detection within the subcscription, or wrap your `.next()` call with `NgZone.run()`. See below for a much simpler solution.

---

Your service can just be:

```js
export class GlobalDataService {
  globalData?: GlobalData;
}
```

to set the data:

```js
export class OneComponent {
  constructor(private globalDataService: GlobalDataService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.globalDataService.globalData = { id1: 1, id2: 2, id3: 3, id4: 4 };
  }
}
```

to get the data, inject the service with the `public` identifier and use the data directly in your html.

```js
export class TwoComponent {
  constructor(public globalDataService: GlobalDataService) {}
}
```

```html
<pre>{{globalDataService.globalData | json}}</pre>
```

Change detection will pick up any changes and update the html accordingly.

You only need the observable if you want some other side effects to happen on change, rather than just updating the html.

Comment: GlobalData is a model. export interface GlobalData {
    id1: number;
    id2: number;
    id3: number;
    id4: number;
}

Comment: @DavidJackson what's your point? If you're referring to the part where I said "I have no idea what this is" I was referring to your two lines of code that I pasted below.

Comment: @DavidJackson if you're confused, `x` is of type `GlobalData`, so i'm assuming that's the data you want. Then `this.globalData` is of type `GlobalData[]` yet when you assign to it, you completely ignore x and instead try to use this mysterious `params?.data?.id`. I'm just completely baffled as to what those two lines of code are.

Comment: oh got it. I was trying to assign only one of the ids from GlobalData and that was taken from params which is used for another function

Comment: So you're attempting to assign a `number` to a `GlobalData[]` and completely ignoring `x`, which is the `GlobalData` you want. I'm still confused as to what you're tying to do.

Comment: globalDataObj: GlobalData, globalData.id1 = <id1 val>, this.globalDataService.globalData$.subscribe( x=> this.globalData = globalData);

Comment: If you have other relevant code then please edit your question. I have no idea what you're trying to say.